# Difference between explode and explode_outer

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What is the difference between [explode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#explode) and [explode_outer](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.0/api/sql/index.html#explode_outer)? The documentation for both functions is the same and also the examples for both functions are identical:

```sql
SELECT explode(array(10, 20));
 10
 20
```

and

```sql
SELECT explode_outer(array(10, 20));
 10
 20
```

The [Spark source](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39510b0e9b79ca59c073bed2219d35d4b81fb7f1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L203) suggests that there is a difference between the two functions

```scala
expression[Explode]("explode"),
expressionGeneratorOuter[Explode]("explode_outer")
```

but what is the effect of [expressionGeneratorOuter](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39510b0e9b79ca59c073bed2219d35d4b81fb7f1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L699) compared to [expression](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39510b0e9b79ca59c073bed2219d35d4b81fb7f1/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/FunctionRegistry.scala#L586)?

Comment: You can also find more info around when to use which function from here. https://medium.com/data-engineering-lab/exploding-array-columns-in-pyspark-explode-vs-explode-outer-5f6a014378f0?sk=deb5bd4f9aa0a38cf2ddb3eda55163c6

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`explode` creates a row for each element in the array or map column by ignoring null or empty values in array whereas `explode_outer` returns all values in array or map including null or empty.

For example, for the following dataframe-

```
id | name | likes
_______________________________
1  | Luke | [baseball, soccer]
2  | Lucy | null
```

`explode` gives the following output-

```
id | name | likes
_______________________________
1  | Luke | baseball
1  | Luke | soccer
```

Whereas `explode_outer` gives the following output-

```
id | name | likes
_______________________________
1  | Luke | baseball
1  | Luke | soccer
2  | Lucy | null
```

---

```sql
SELECT explode(col1) from values (array(10,20)), (null)
```

returns

```
+---+
|col|
+---+
| 10|
| 20|
+---+
```

while

```sql
SELECT explode_outer(col1) from values (array(10,20)), (null)
```

returns

```
+----+
| col|
+----+
|  10|
|  20|
|null|
+----+
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still do not understand the difference. For example `SELECT explode(array(10, 20, null))` (an array with null) also gives the same result for both functions. Do you have an example where the functions return different results?

Comment: Certainly. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: adding a query/code sample showing the usage of these functions would be better.

Comment: What will happen in case the input data looks like this: [,] @werner