# Extract columns from a json and write into a dataframe

Tags: json, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following string:

```
{
    "code": 4,
    "results": [
        {
            "requests": 100,
            "requests_country": 291,
            "listing": {
                "first": 1,
                "second": 2
            }
        },
        {
            "requests": 200,
            "requests_country": 292,
            "listing": {
                "first": 10,
                "second": 220
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I would like to extract certain values in order to create a dataframe.
This is the desired output:

```
+---------+----------------+
| requests|requests_country|
+---------+----------------+
|  100    |291             |
|  200    |292             |
+---------+----------------+
```

I tried a lot of methods but none work.

I tried converting to map and then use `parse` to extract results but I keep getting errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `explode_outer`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{col, explode_outer}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .master("local")
    .appName("Spark app")
    .getOrCreate()

  val df = spark.read.json("src/main/resources/file.json")
  df.show()
  //+----+--------------------+
  //|code|             results|
  //+----+--------------------+
  //|   4|[{{1, 2}, 100, 29...|
  //+----+--------------------+

  val df1 = df.select(explode_outer(col("results")))
  df1.show()
  //+--------------------+
  //|                 col|
  //+--------------------+
  //|  {{1, 2}, 100, 291}|
  //|{{10, 220}, 200, ...|
  //+--------------------+

  val df2 = df1.select(col("col.requests"), col("col.requests_country"))
  df2.show()
  //+--------+----------------+
  //|requests|requests_country|
  //+--------+----------------+
  //|     100|             291|
  //|     200|             292|
  //+--------+----------------+
}
```

*file.json*

```
{"code": 4, "results": [{"requests": 100, "requests_country": 291, "listing": {"first": 1, "second": 2}}, {"requests": 200, "requests_country": 292, "listing": {"first": 10, "second": 220 }}]}
```

[How to translate a complex nested JSON structure into multiple columns in a Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75288662/how-to-translate-a-complex-nested-json-structure-into-multiple-columns-in-a-spar)

[Cannot cast dataframe column containing an array to String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75336634/cannot-cast-dataframe-column-containing-an-array-to-string)

[Difference between explode and explode_outer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64377894/difference-between-explode-and-explode-outer)